# Space $C'[0,1]$ open closed or neither

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is the subset $C'[0,1]$ of differentiable functions with continuous derivative of the set of continuous functions $C[0,1]$ open closed or neither with respect to the sup metric. I would say not closed because a differentiable function can converge to a function that is not differentiable, however I am not sure about open. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you supposed to guess the distance that you are working with?

Comment: sup metric it is

Comment: That should be part of the question, instead of being a comment.

Comment: it says with respect to the sup metric

Comment: Right. I missed that.

Comment: Most likely not.  I can imagine a C' function plus a non- differentiable function with very tiny ($\lt \epsilon$) wiggles added.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I am confused by your comment

Comment: For any interval of length $\epsilon$ around a given C' function, the C' function plus a tiny bad function will be inside the interval.  Therefore you can't have an open interval around any C' function containing only C' functions.